# Epplus generated charts missing in Numbers

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, .net-core, epplus

I've found out a compatibility issue, trying to save .xlsx file with Epplus.Core library.

If I open generated file in Excel 2016, everything is perfect, but if I use macOs or iOs Numbers application, then all the charts dissapear.

I get an error:

> "Charts of unsupported type or size were either imported as an image or removed".

Also want to notice, that during tests sometimes charts appeared in file, but axis had wrong scale (values were about 4kk, but axis max limit was just 4).

It's very important for me to create file, that could be read correctly in both Excel and Numbers applications.

I've thought about exporting worksheet to .pdf, but I have several worksheets, and it would be problem to export two files (one .xlsx with data and another one .pdf with charts) in one moment.

Is there any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was in naming of worksheet with chart's datatable.

It should be ***no spaces*** in worksheet name, then Apple Numbers successfully display all the charts.

Also chart with type = `eChartType.BarClustered` can become a problem.

I don't know why, but Apple Numbers throw an error, if there is chart with this type on worksheet.